# Библиотека algorithm sort и find/ C++

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

В общем дали лабораторную. В ней реализовать работу автосалона (к примеру, у меня  клас car с переменными string (название), и double (цена); потом клас автосалон в котором vector ). Надо сделать sort и find (по разным полям) используя algorithm. Не могу разобраться.

```
сlass Car {
string _name;
size_t _year;
double _engine;
double _price;

public:
    Car(string name = "ЗАЗ 965", size_t year = 1975, double engine = 1.2, double price = 494.20)
        : _name(name), _year(year), _engine(engine), _price(price) {}
    bool operator==(Car & c) {
        return _name == c._name&&_year == c._year
            &&_engine == c._engine&&_price == c._price;
    }

    bool operator!=(Car & c) {
        return _name != c._name&&_year != c._year
            &&_engine != c._engine&&_price != c._price;
    }
}

    class Showroom {
    vector<Car> _cars;
public:
    void SearchName(Car name) {
        vector<Car>::iterator it;

        it = find(_cars.begin(), _cars.end(), name);//проблема здесь
        //не могу понять что надо сделать
        cout << (it - _cars.begin()) << endl;

        system("pause");
    }
}
```

По разным полям то-есть сортировка по названию, по дате, по цене.

Comment: сделайте operator== и operator< для car.

Comment: К сожалению, в нашем сообществе Вам не напишут код. Здесь Вам могут дать лишь указания по решению задачи. Также советую избегать просьб о помощи. Удачи!

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, выложите необходимый и достаточный пример того, что сделали сами и конкретно опишите, в чем у вас проблема и что вы хотите получить в результате. *Сделать sort и find* - это не вопрос. Тем более не понятно, что значит *по разным полям*.